# How to create "change" event handlers dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create dropdown dynamically.

Their ids are `ddl1`, `ddl2`, `ddl3` and so on.

```
$('#ddl1').focus(function() {
    var previous = this.value;
}).change(function() {
    var index = $(this).find('selected').index();
    $('#ddl1').find('option:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
    $('#ddl2').find('option:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
});

$('#ddl2').focus(function() {
...
```

Creation of 7 dropdowns makes me to write 7 `change` event handlers.

How to implement dynamically create change event?

My dropdown append methods are:

```
var x=1;
var dropdown=('#ddl1').html();
$('#btnadd').click(function() {    
   $('#divname').append('<select id="ddl'+x+' > </select> <option>../option>');
   x++;    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a common class to every dropdown and refer to that. Also, use `.on()` (event delegation) to catch dynamic created elements:

```
$(document).on('change', '.common-class', function() {
   //Your function
   var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Add the same class every time you append a `select` element:

```
//...
$('#divname').append('<select id="ddl'+ x + '" class="common-class"><option>../option></select>');
```

**SELECTED OPTION**

In order to get the selected option:

```
$('#current-id').find('option:selected').index();
```

Comment: Common class are get current dropdown id ?

Comment: Please provide some HTML to better understand the structure

Comment: Thanku so much kapantzak .

Comment: ,Please help.I can't get selected value,$(currentid).find(':selected').index(); This jquery return -1

Answer (score 1):

Variant without delegated events to reduce resource usage:

```
var $dds = $('select');

$dds.each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    processDdChange($this);
});

function processDdChange($obj) {
    $obj.on('change', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        alert($this.attr('id') + ' | ' + $this.find(':selected').val());
});
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tasmanangel/2p9mbs7h/